# How to check style BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON of button

Tags: c++

I want to save properties of controls in a window such as text or checked or etc in **WinAPI**.

How can i test the ***button controls*** that has **BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON** style (Is it CheckBox or RadioButton )?

Comment: Are you asking for [`BM_GETCHECK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775986(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetWindowLong()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the style of a window:

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
if(0 != (style & BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON))
{
    // radio button logic here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not quite right. Check out `BS_TYPEMASK`.